# Retrofit 2 void return

Tags: retrofit2

In Retrofit 2, service methods representing http methods must return `Call`.

`Call` is a generic which must take the type representing the return object of the http method.

For example,

```
@GET("/members/{id}")
Call<Member> getMember(@Path("id") Long id);
```

For http methods such as delete, no content is returned. In cases like this, what parameter should be provided to `Call`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I handle empty response body with Retrofit 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228126/how-can-i-handle-empty-response-body-with-retrofit-2)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just set Void as the Type.

```
@DELETE("/members/{id}")
Call<Void> removeMember(@Path("id") Long id);
```

Comment: And how does one then setup the callback?

Comment: @Zapnologica .enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {  public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) { ... }  public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) { ... } });

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kotlin/Retrofit/Rxjava/RxKotlin

```
@Headers(JwtKeyTokenWithValue)
@DELETE("/members/{id}")
fun removeMember(@Path("id") Long id): Completable
```

And can be subscribed this way

```
apiManager
       .removeMember()
       .subscribe(
           { Timber.i { "Member Removed!" } },
           { t -> Timber.e(t)})
```