# Retrofit 2.0 beta 4 response get IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 1.9 and i created logout method as

```
@GET("/user/logout")
void logoutUser(Callback<Response> callback);

logoutUser(new RequestCallback<Response>(this) {
    @Override
    public void success(Response response, Response response2) {
        settingsService.setUserLoggedOut();
        getMainActivity().finish();
    }
});
```

i upgraded it to retrofit 2.0 beta 4 and used this code

```
@GET("user/logout")
Call<Response> logoutUser();

logoutUser().enqueue(new RequestCallback<Response>(this) {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {
        settingsService.setUserLoggedOut();
        getMainActivity().finish();
    }
});
```

I have this exception :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'retrofit2.Response' is not a valid response body type. Did you mean ResponseBody?

what is the problem?

Comment: did you add ToGsonConverterFactory ?

Comment: @ankitaggarwal  yes i did
...
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to overcome this by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33228322

So try:

```
@GET("user/logout")
Call<ResponseBody> logoutUser();
```

Where `ResponseBody` is an `okhttp3.ResponseBody`

and then

```
logoutUser().enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

...

});
```

Comment: Is this the only option?

What If I don't care about the response body. I just want a  StatusCode 200 or 400 etc?