# Retrofit2 OkHttp3 Response Body Null Error

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit 2 to call a microservice which returns a 200 and an empty response body on a PUT method.
Retrofit 2 however seems to not be able to handle this and in the "enqueue" goes to the onFailure branch
@Override
public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {

Here are the logs:

```
Mai 27, 2017 3:26:49 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFORMATION: --> PUT http://127.0.0.1/test/ http/1.1
Mai 27, 2017 3:26:49 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFORMATION: Content-Type: application/vnd.tipico.notification-v1+json
Mai 27, 2017 3:26:49 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFORMATION: Content-Length: 87
Mai 27, 2017 3:26:49 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFORMATION: 
Mai 27, 2017 3:26:49 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFORMATION: {"state":"ACTIVE","externalId":"abcd","loginName":"gsdfgsdf","updatedAt":1495531062000}
Mai 27, 2017 3:26:49 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFORMATION: --> END PUT (87-byte body)
Mai 27, 2017 3:26:50 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFORMATION: <-- 200  http://127.0.0.1/test/ (197ms)
Mai 27, 2017 3:26:50 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFORMATION: X-Application-Context: customer-care-notification-service:49980
Mai 27, 2017 3:26:50 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFORMATION: Content-Length: 0
Mai 27, 2017 3:26:50 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFORMATION: Date: Sat, 27 May 2017 13:26:49 GMT
Mai 27, 2017 3:26:50 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFORMATION: <-- END HTTP (0-byte body)
15:26:50,030 ERROR com.test.app.Test - Failed CCNS call com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: okhttp3.ResponseBody$BomAwareReader@9eb187b; line: 1, column: 0]
```

Anyone knows what causes this? Since the request is served successfully (see above).

Comment: That's quite weird. Does your call return any object which retrofit might try to deserialise? by call I mean the java interface

Comment: Did you find solution? I am facing same problem. Looks like this is happening with some jackson releases. Which version you're using?

Comment: Hi, yes you need to implement NullOnEmptyConverterFactory like here https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1554

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I handle empty response body with Retrofit 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228126/how-can-i-handle-empty-response-body-with-retrofit-2)

Answer (score 2):

I created a Null handler converter for this issue:

```
public class NullOnEmptyConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {

    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        final Converter<ResponseBody, ?> delegate = retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(this, type, annotations);
        return (Converter<ResponseBody, Object>) body -> {
            if (body.contentLength() == 0) return null;
            return delegate.convert(body);
        };
    }
}
```

You need to add this converter before your Gson converter

```
.addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
```