# Handle Void and Non-Void response with Retrofit 2 and RxJava 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have a call to send data to the server. If everything is ok, the server returns a void response. But when there is an error I get data back.

To manage the case when there is an error I have a `CustomResponse` object. The issue is that when the request is successful Retrofit throws an Exception with the message: `java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $`

Here is the call:

```
@POST("/updateObject")
Observable<CustomResponse> updateObject(@Body CustomObject requestData);
```

I did a bit of researches and I read that I could use `Observable<Response<Void>> ...` but in that case how I'm supposed to manage when the response contains data?

Comment: what's the actual response when its successful though? is there really no body at all?

Comment: The response is: `OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (0-byte body)` so there is really no body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I handle empty response body with Retrofit 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228126/how-can-i-handle-empty-response-body-with-retrofit-2)

Comment: @NoActivity.java It partially solve the issue. I've personally solved it using [this answer](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1554#issuecomment-178633697)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but I would start with creating a wrapper class that has your `CustomResponse` as a nullable.

Something like this:

```
public class SomeWrapper {
    @Nullable CustomResponse customResponse;
}
```

Then in your Retrofit/Rx call, you can change it to this:

```
@POST("/updateObject")
Observable<SomeWrapper> updateObject(@Body CustomObject requestData);
```

give that a shot, and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thx, but it doesn't work. Retrofit tries to parse the JSON but because there is no body it still fails.